# AngularJS website works in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

For some reason, my website doesn't work in Chrome.

I've pinpointed it down to a gallery controller. It seems that if it's present, the whole app cannot work in Chrome. Apparently, it could be because Firefox autocompletes tags. However, the problem lies only in the Angular app itself. If I change the order of the 's, and put the section with the gallery last, the website remains unbroken in Chrome, BUT, the gallery is.

```
app.controller('GalleryCtrl', function ($scope, Lightbox) {
  $scope.images = [
    {
      'url': 'https://www.kreo-it.pl/ResponsiveWebDesign.jpg',
      'thumbUrl': 'https://www.kreo-it.pl/rwdthumb.jpg',
    },
    ];

   $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
    Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
  };

});

app.controller('GalleryCtrl1', function ($scope, Lightbox) {
  $scope.images = [
    {
      'url': 'https://www.kreo-it.pl/BannerTemplate.jpg',
      'thumbUrl': 'https://www.kreo-it.pl/bthumb.jpg',
    },
    ];

  $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
   Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
  };

});

app.controller('GalleryCtrl2', function ($scope, Lightbox) {
  $scope.images = [
    {
      'url': 'https://www.kreo-it.pl/VisualIdentity.jpg',
      'thumbUrl': 'https://www.kreo-it.pl/vithumb.jpg',
    },
    ];

  $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
    Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
  };

 });
```

This is the code of the controller(s). I'm using multiple, because I haven't found a solution that will give me 3 single lightboxes that do not interact with eachother in a single controller. Anyhow, my questions are:

- Why do websites work in Firefox, but not in Chrome, generally?
- What can I do to fix the lightbox gallery?
- Is there a way I can make this design more efficient.

Thanks. The website in question is www.kreo-it.pl, click the "PORTFOLIO" tab. As you can see, the gallery works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: At least one problem is you are loading angular-route.js before angular.js

Comment: Thank you! However, this didn't fix my issue. The website works just fine in IE, Firefox and Safari. There must be a feature in Chrome that breaks the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i have test your site in both browsers. All are working fine in chrome also. here attached Screenshot from my browsers. popup open perfect. yes i check there are issue from data loading. Your image size is high resolution so take load time for view image on popup. also rename all image with lowercase.

[image: chrome tested]